# windows onbeforeunload doesn't work Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload, onbeforeunload

I want to prevent a close tab or close browser in a web page.
I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { //Doesn't work well
        return 'Exit';
    };

    $('#form').submit(function() { //No alert on submit form (this works)
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
</script>
```

If I click somewhere in the page the code works fine and ask me if I really want to close the page, but if I reload the page and then I close the tab without click something in the page the tab close without show any alert.

Do you have some idea how to fix?

Comment: You didn't perform any action on the page, so what *"data [the user] ha[s] entered may not be saved*"?

Comment: I need a function that prevent page reload, tab close, browser close in ANY CASE, form filled, form not filled, focus on page or not.

Comment: Just like many intrusive popups? Such things are not really liked any more.

Comment: This code also if the form is all filled but the page is not focussed (I mean I don't click somewhere after the first reload) the page reload without any alert

Comment: That is a browser feature, unless the user has done some action within the page onbeforeunload won't trigger a popup

Comment: So there is no way to prevent a tab close without any action?

Comment: @Wal that's right. Why halt the user from leaving the page if he hasn't even interacted with it?

Comment: So how the spam website do that? Doing nothing and closing the tab 100000 popups appear

Comment: "To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all. " -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility); So, that basically works as what browsers / users want. You cannot / should not change it.

Comment: @Wal If any site successfully opened millions of popups without any user interaction, you should report this to browser's developers since it is a terrible browser bug.